# IsDtypeValidation-issue for dtype string with pandas_schema-module

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dtype

I am trying to confirm a column in a dataframe is of the dtype 'string'. For this I use the package pandas_schema.

The below code-snippet confirms when a column is not of the dtype 'string'. However, when the dtype is actually correct, the code fails and returns the error `TypeError: Cannot interpret 'StringDtype' as a data type`.

Is my code faulty?

I know I could simply check the if `series.convert_dtypes().dtype` returns `string`. But I prefer to add this check to the other checks in the `pandas_schema.schema.Schema`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_schema.validation import IsDtypeValidation

series = pd.Series(["a", "b", "c"])

# Works as expected:
#   Returns a validation warning as the series is of dtype 'object' and not 'string'.
print(f"dtype = {series.dtypes}")  # Returns: dtype = object
idv = IsDtypeValidation(dtype=np.dtype(np.str))
validation_warnings = idv.get_errors(series=series)
print(validation_warnings[0])  # Returns: The column  has a dtype of object which is not a subclass of the required type <U0

# But we know that the series only contains string-values. Thus convert_dtypes() in this snippet.
# Does not work as expected:
#   Returns an error and traceback with 'TypeError: Cannot interpret 'StringDtype' as a data type'.
#   Expected output should be no error or validation warning.
series = series.convert_dtypes()
print(f"dtype = {series.dtypes}")  # Returns: dtype = string
idv = IsDtypeValidation(dtype=np.dtype(np.str))
validation_warnings = idv.get_errors(series=series)  # Error occurs in this line.
```

Comment: `pandas` does not use the `numpy` string dtype.  Strings are stored as Python strings in object dtype Series.

Comment: How would I use that in ```IsDtypeValidation(dtype=...)```?. Using ```dtype=str``` or ```dtype=np.dtype('<U0')``` does not work. I also tried applying the pandas dtype directly, which also didn't work: ```dtype=series.convert_dtypes().dtype```.

Comment: Playing around with `convert_dtypes` I see that `pandas` has added a `StringDtype` (and a `StringArray` class).  This is **not** the same as `np.str` (or any `numpy` variation).   I don't have `pandas_schema`, so can't help you with adjusting its testing to accommodate this pandas extension dtype.

Comment: The repository owner confirmed it is a bug: https://github.com/TMiguelT/PandasSchema/issues/39.